# Encontrar los elementos centrales de un arreglo

Tags: javascript

necesito encontrar los elementos centrales de un arreglo de números, pero para elementos pares, necesito que me retorne un arreglo con los dos números centrales.

```js
function findArray(array) {
  if (array.length%2 === 0) {
    return `${array[array.length/2 -1]} ${array[array.length/2]}`;
  } else {
    return array[(array.length-1)/2];
  }
}

console.log(findArray([1, 2, 3, 42, 59, 6, 7,]))
```

Como se ve en la primera parte me regresa strings, pero necesito un areglo.

Comment: ¿Podrias mostrar un ejemplo de la salida que necesitas?  Es que no acabo de entender eso de los dos números centrales para elementos pares de tu array `[1, 2, 3, 42, 59, 6, 7,]` ¿Cuales serian en este ejemplo?

Comment: el arreglo podría tener  elementos impares [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] la salida sería el numero 3 porque es el central.
si el arreglo tiene elementos pares [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] la salida sería [3, 4] ya que ambos son elementos centrales

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar esa explicación a la pregunta?  Puedes pulsar sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta para ello. De este modo la pregunta quedará más clara y obtendrás mejores respuestas, gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Resumen**

El código es una función que recibe un arreglo de números y retorna un arreglo con uno o dos números centrales.

**Explicación**

- Se crea una variable `result` que almacenará los valores centrales del arreglo dado.
- La variable `middle` almacenará el valor índice para ubicarnos exactamente en la mitad de nuestro arreglo.
- Verificamos si el arreglo tiene una longitud par o impar.
- En caso de que sea par, obtendremos dos valores centrales, de lo contrario, solo obtendremos un valor central.
- Por ultimo, retornamos nuestro arreglo `result` que contendrá **nuestro**/s **valor**/es **central**/es.

**Por ejemplo:**

```javascript
filtrar([0, 3, 53, 1]) // [3, 53]
filtrar([5, 7, 23])    // [7]
```

### Solución

```js
function findArray(array) {
    let result = [];
    let middle = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
    if (array.length % 2 === 0) {
        result.push(array[middle - 1]);
    }
    result.push(array[middle]);
    return result;
}

console.log('longitud impar:', findArray([1, 2, 3, 42, 59, 6, 7]));
console.log('longitud par:', findArray([1, 2, 3, 42, 59, 6]));
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, aunque las respuestas con solo código son consideradas de baja calidad y pueden recibir votos negativos. Por favor, explica brevemente el porque esa respuesta es la adecuada a la pregunta para que la comunidad pueda entenderlo mejor. Al igual que las preguntas, las respuestas deberían ser autocontenidas y poderse entender por si solas. Gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias, enseguida redacto mi explicación.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por tu colaboración!

Comment: Como nota, ya que ambas partes de tu condición ejecutan la sentencia `result.push(array[middle]);` yo la movería a fuera del condicional, es decir, ejecutas esa sentencia y luego compruebas si la longitud es par, y si lo es simplemente haces el push del middle - 1, no hay necesidad de else, se simplifica el código y es más fácil y rápido de leer :)

Comment: @Benito-B Tienes toda la razón, gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: @Azt3kCode te he editado la respuesta para convertir el código en un snippet (igual que con la pregunta), así se puede ejecutar directamente para demostrar el funcionamiento. Además añadí un caso de prueba con número de argumentos par. Por lo demás, excelente respuesta y redacción :)